# Azure - ASP.NET Core FileNotFoundException

Tags: azure, phantomjs

I have an ASP.NET Core webapp hosted in an Azure AppService (Basic plan - B1) and I am using phantomjs to generate some pdf from html (based on https://github.com/TheSalarKhan/PhantomJs.NetCore).

The problem is that the second time I generate the pdf the app crashes with the FileNotFoundException when the process is started - see https://github.com/TheSalarKhan/PhantomJs.NetCore/blob/d580fba1128756acc8384107a17b399397475dad/PdfGenerator.cs#L54 (I am using Windows 
 => windows_phantomjs.exe) - the first time works fine. I tried to recopy windows_phantomjs.exe from wwwroot to PhantomJSRoot but again I get a FileNotFoundException when I do:

```
File.Copy("D:\home\site\wwwroot\windows_phantomjs.exe", "D:\home\site\wwwroot\PhantomJSRoot\windows_phantomjs.exe", true);

Exception Info: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\windows_phantomjs.exe'.
```

The strange thing is that the files do exist in both locations - I used the Diagnostic console to view the Azure file system.

Any ideas on how to workaround this? On dev box (macOS) the code works fine second time, third time, and so on...

Answer (score 0):

Use Kudu to upload your file directly to the location. Probably exe is deleted on server side by malware detection tools. Sandboxing, I suggest you run this in a container.

Comment: By using kudu I can see that the exe fie is on the Azure file system... It's like the app is running from a different folder where the file does not exist...

Comment: Read about sandbox and limitations https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox i am sure it is the issue

Comment: I am aware of those - that's why I use a Basic+ plan. But then why does it work the first time? If I changed the plan to Free, then it does not work the first time either (which is normal, according to the limitations).